# Program to count max amount of combinations to divide number without remainder

Tags: python, combinations

For example we want to build a tower which height is 21. We have two types of bricks, one's height is 3 second's 5.
We have two solutions

```
5+5+5+3+3 = 21 # 5

3+3+3+3+3+3+3=21 # 7 is max so we return it
```

If it can't be divided we just output nothing.

```
h,a,b=21,3,5
for i in range(h//a+1,0,-1):
 for j in range(0,h//b+1):
  if i*a+b*j==h:print(i+j);exit()
```

Is there a faster solution?

Comment: Here you don't count, you just print. So what do you want : a faster solution as said in the post, or a solution that counts as said in title ?

Comment: Yeah it just outputs the number, I want better solution which works faster than this one